# How do I handle a permission denied exception at a 404 page?

Tags: javascript, firebug, http-status-code-404, greasemonkey, permission-denied

I am trying to write a greasemonkey script which checks in firefox if a page shows a 404 error. If it does, the script should reload the page. The schript looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        404-reloader
// @namespace   None
// @include     *
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

url = "http://www.example.com";

if (document.getElementById("errorPageContainer"))
    location.href = url;
```

My problem is, it works only sometimes. To test it I turned off my wireless adapter and loaded a page. The script didn't itself so I started it manually. The first time I started it the script worked and changed to example.com, where I got another not found error, because the adapter was still turned off. I started the script again and it worked. After the third time I got an exception in the script:

```
/*
Exception: Permission denied to access property 'document'
@Scratchpad/2:10
*/
```

I found out that when I change the URL, the Script workes one time. Afterwards I get this exception.
When the script didn't work I copied it into the firebug console and ran it. It worked there but still not in the greasemonkey script.

Now I would like to know why greasemonkey behaves like this and how I handle the problem with the Exception and the problem that Greasemonkey doesn't run by itself on a 404 page.

I already searched for answers but haven't find anything useful for my problem.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I thought it's a feature actually that GM doesn't run on error pages, anyway, this works for me:

Instead of running at `document-end` which is default, when you run at `document-start` and add a listener for `DOMContentLoaded`, it works well for me even when reloading. Note though that `@run-at` is GM-specific (>=1.0), not portable so far to Chrome/Opera as far as I know.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test123
// @namespace   test123
// @version     1
// @include     *
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById('errorPageContainer'));
});
```

Comment: I tried to include that into my script and afterwards copied it exactly how you wrote it, but it doesn't work :( it still doesn't run at start and I still get the permission denied error. I also checked my greasemonkey version: 1.9

Comment: Well I've cut some metadata in the original post (notably `@include`), does it work now? Firefox 22, GM 1.9

Comment: No, I still get the same errors. I copied the script exactly how it stand there and tried it. Aftarwards I made some changes to experiment with it but it doesn't work. Is there any setting I have to change in Firefox or GM? Does it run in your browser? I have FF21, GM1.9. Could this be a bug in FF21?